# Structured archive with multiple domain objects that inherit from common class

Tags: ocean, petrel

I'm writing an Ocean plugin for Petrel and need to persist some custom domain objects, and everything seems to point to using a structured archive data source. I've created a common class to hold a lot of the standard domain object stuff (droid, name, color, image, comments, history, etc), to avoid rewriting it for every domain object I create. The Ocean development guide only has simple examples of classes with no inheritance, but given that everything has a version number, I foresee a potential problem when the base class version is different than the version of inherited-class-1 which is different than inherited-class-2, and then I update something in the base class.

Is it possible to use a structured archive with the common base class? Are there any special considerations for versioning, or anything else I need to be aware of?

ETA: A simple class diagram showing the relationships and some stuff I've tried

```
public abstract class ClassA
                    |
       -----------------------------------
       |                                 |
public class ClassB : ClassA       public classC : ClassA


public class ClassD
{
    private List<ClassA> _myClassAObjects;
}
```

All classes are marked `Archivable`, and in `ClassD`, `_myClassAObjects` is marked `Archived`. Everything saves OK, but when I load, I get an `InvalidCastException`, as it tries to cast the `List<ClassB>` to a `List<ClassA>`. The casting should work, since `ClassB` inherits from `ClassA`, should it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from Schlumberger. It is possible, by doing something like this:

```
[Archivable]
public abstract class Abstract CDO
{

    [ArchivableContextInject]
    protected StructuredArchiveDataSource DataSourceCore;

    [Archived(Name = "Name")]
    private string _name;

    private AbstractCDO _parent;

    [Archived(Name="ParentDroid")]
    private Droid _parentDroid;

    [Archived(Name = "Droid")]
    protected Droid DroidCore
    {
        get { return _droid; }
        set
        {
            if (_droid != value)
            {
                DataSourceCore.IsDirty = true;
                _droid = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public Droid ParentDroid
    {
        get { return _parentDroid; }
        set
        {
            if (_parentDroid != value)
            {
                DataSourceCore.IsDirty = true;
                _parentDroid = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public AbstractCDO Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
        set
        {
            if (_parent != value)
            {
                DataSourceCore.IsDirty = true;
                _parent = value;
                _parentDroid = _parent.Droid;
            }
        }
    }

    protected AbstractCDO(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        DataSourceCore = Factory.Get();
        _droid = DataSourceCore.GenerateDroid();
        DataSourceCore.AddItem(_droid, this);
    }

}

[Archivable]
public abstract class AbstractCDOCollection : AbstractCDO, IObservableElementList
{

    [Archived]
    private List<AbstractCDO> _children;

    protected AbstractCDO(string name) : base(name) { }

    public List<AbstractCDO> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }

}

[Archivable]
public class ConcreteObject : AbstractCDO
{

    public ConcreteObject(string name) : base(name)
    {
        // other stuff
    }

}
```

The DataSource property needs to be protected since the injection had a bug which was fixed in Petrel 2013.3 / 2014.1.